# Question on Power Sets: if $|A|=n$, what is $|P(P(A))|$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

(Let $P$ be the symbol for Power Sets)

My exercise states, if $|A|=n$, what is $|P(P(A))|$?

The given answer is:

If $|A| = n$, then $|P(A)| = 2^n$ and $|P(P(A))| = 2^{2^n}$. 
For $n = 2$, we have $|P(P(A))| = 2^4 = 16.$

Where does the 2 come from in the if statement?

Thanks,

Tony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every subset of a set with cardinality $n$ can be expressed as a sequence of $0$ and $1$ with size $n$. $0$ corresponds to the absence of an element in the subset and $1$ to its presence. There are $2^n$ of these sequences because for each member of sequence we have 2 choices: $0$ and $1$ and because the sequence has size $n$, we have  $2\times 2\dots\times 2=2^n$ possibilities.

Comment: Hi Arash, thanks for the quick reply. This makes sense now.